# Sitecore: how to move a Field to one of my Base Templates without losing data

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8

Let's say that my "Toyota" template has "Car" as its Base Template.

I want to move the field "Windshield" from "Toyota" to "Car", but I don't want all instances of Toyota to have it reset to null.

Is there a safe way to go about doing this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes.
In the content editor you can move the item that represents the "Windshield" field to your Car template. The ID of the field will stay the same, so you will not loose that data.

The field item can be found in the children of your template item..

Comment: Just drag and drop in Content Editor? That's it?

Comment: Yep. Anything that makes a move, to keep the ID.